# Variables input generation for Minimization in High dimensional space

Tags: mathematical-optimization, variable-definitions, code-generation

I'm currently doing optimization in a high dimensional space. I was thinking of giving `FindMinimum` (or `NMinimize` not certain yet) a shot, however what bugs me is how I can state the command, given that its input a vector of size ~200.

Most examples for `FindMinimum` have functions of at most 2 variables.

Now I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6628349/152244]) on StackOverflow where the user generates all his variables using

```
vars = Array[Symbol["x$" <> ToString[#]] &, n];
```

However reading the comments showed that there were certain concerns with this method:

> I would not recommend doing it in a program, but it is safe to do in an interactive session.

So is this standard, or is there a more clever solution to get to it ?

Comment: Also check out [Making Definitions for Indexed Objects](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)

Comment: @shrx It is not about assigning. Creation of symbols is solved, comment's to linked answer are OP's concern.

Comment: @Kuba in that case I'm retracting my vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

The point being made in the quoted answer was to not use the `name$number` convention, because `Module` usues it, and who knows what conflicts might happen internally if you were to generate such variables. Using `x$$$`s in place of `x$` would be fine.

Comment: Using `Unique` would also be acceptable.